# Creating ArcCatalog-friendly xml metadata file from url metadata?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, xml, metadata, arccatalog

How do you take metadata information from a url like [this](https://www.geosask.ca/Portal/DiscoveryServlet?command=viewmetadata&uuid=%7B90A822F0-EAF5-5561-2793-C74EDDEDACF4%7D) and create an xml file that ArcCatalog's "import xml" metadata tool will accept?

I have tried a few variations on pasting the url information into a text editor and saving as xml but haven't found the right method.

I am using ArcGIS Desktop 10.

Comment: There is no straightforward way to convert HTML metadata to XML metadata. Are there any alternative parameters to the URL that return metadata in XML format?

Comment: none that I could find.

Comment: The download zip contains an xsl file.  Have you tried using the XSL file to do the transform?

Answer (score 1):

Unless I'm wrong, they've transformed the XML to formatted HTML. Not sure if there is an easy way to reverse that. Not sure why, but I downloaded the SURN11.zip file and it doesn't have any metadata xml there. ftp://portaldata:freedata@ftp.isc.ca/PackagedData/ISC/SURN.zip Maybe just contact them. I'm sure they have it given the HTML that they are showing.

Comment: The SURN.zip actually does have several metadata files http://i.imgur.com/dmBIAxz.png  but I couldn't get the ArcCatalog import tool to accept any of them.

Comment: See if you can post them somewhere online and then someone can take a look.

Comment: they (the metadata files) are all in the zip file here: ftp://portaldata:freedata@ftp.isc.ca/PackagedData/ISC/SURN.zip